# Angular2 to render mustache tags without using mustache.js?

Tags: angular, typescript, mustache, mailmerge

Angular2+ renders mustache tags of the view model in HTML template into HTML content, so it obviously has already got the engine of rendering mustache tags as mustache.js could.

In my Angular2+ app, I would like to generate letters (mail merge) according to a letter template with mustache tags. Are there Angular2+ API to render, without needing mustache.js?

My use case is, I would like to do mail merge to generate HTML document/text/string to be sent by Email, or saved to the Cloud storage. All done in the browser.

Comment: I think that this needs some more details about what you are trying to do.... If I understand correctly... In your new Angular app you are trying to use / render existing HTML templates that include mustache tags but don't want to upgrade the templates into Angular?

Comment: I second this comment. This is too broad to understand. Show us some code or something

Comment: My use case is, I would like to do mail merge to create HTML document to be sent by Email, or saved to the Cloud storage. All done in the browser.